# How to remove toggle drop down on swiftUI list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm having a problem on list swiftUI
I want to remove toggle drop down (black circle), without disabling the function of toggle, so the list of names (blue line) is appear when the views first load
[image]

Here's my code, maybe it would help to fix my problem

```
struct IphoneProfileView: View {
    @StateObject var companyViewModel = CompanyViewModel()
    @StateObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var employeeListViewModel = EmployeeListViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var role: RoleService = .shared
    var company: Company?
    @State var companyName = ""
    @State var editModeIphone: EditMode = .inactive {
        didSet {
            if editModeIphone.isEditing {
                profileViewModel.isPinHidden = false
            } else {
                profileViewModel.isPinHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section(header: CompanyProfileHeader()) {
                    if editModeIphone.isEditing {
                        CompanyInfoNameTextField(
                            placeholder: "Company Inc.",
                            text: $profileViewModel.company.name
                        )
                        CompanyInfoTextField(
                            title: "Owner PIN",
                            placeholder: "1234",
                            text: $profileViewModel.company.ownerPin
                        )
                    }
                    ReviewPolicy()
                }
                Section(header: EmployeeListHeader()) {
                    ForEach(employeeListViewModel.employees) { employee in
                        EmployeeRow(employee: employee)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: employeeListViewModel.delete)
                    .onAppear {
                        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            EditButton()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Profile", displayMode: .inline)
        .environment(\.editMode, $editModeIphone)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanna your question to be answered, you wanna make time for an expert to get working sample with reproducible problem as fast as possible. Perfectly I should just paste your code into my sample project and see the problem as fast as I run it.  Please add a [minimal reproducible example]

Comment: @Philip im sorry i forgot to put my code inside, i already update my question, hope you can help

Comment: @vandettadyckies Try simplify the code - putting this in a project doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

Very odd, what did the trick for me was to use the list modifier like this:

```swift
.listStyle(.insetGrouped)
```

(Using iOS 16.1 and Xcode 14.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the .listStyle(GroupedListStyle()) on the List, something like this:

```
         List {
            Section(header: CompanyProfileHeader()) {
                if editModeIphone.isEditing {
                    CompanyInfoNameTextField(
                        placeholder: "Company Inc.",
                        text: $profileViewModel.company.name
                    )
                    CompanyInfoTextField(
                        title: "Owner PIN",
                        placeholder: "1234",
                        text: $profileViewModel.company.ownerPin
                    )
                }
                ReviewPolicy()
            }
            Section(header: EmployeeListHeader()) {
                ForEach(employeeListViewModel.employees) { employee in
                    EmployeeRow(employee: employee)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: employeeListViewModel.delete)
                .onAppear {
                    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```